# sprite kit swift, detecting collision for game over

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision, bit-masks

I am currently making my first game. I have a collision function `ballCollideWithWall(_:Ball:)` which is called as expected, but the game over scene is not presenting. I verified that the collision function is called by using `NSLog`.

```
    // game over function
func gameOver(){
    // presenting Game Over Scene
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.5)
    self.view?.presentScene(GameOverScene(), transition: transition)
}
```

which is then called in my function for the collision as

```
func ballCollideWithWall(Wall: SKSpriteNode, Ball: SKSpriteNode) {
    gameOver()
}
```

Comment: maybe you could try this instead on your update?
 if (CGRectContainsPoint(Wall.frame, Ball.frame))
    {
        NSLog(@"touched");
        [self Gameover];
    }

Comment: what happens when the scene is displayed? please give a description so I can give an accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting the scene in wrong way. You should change your code like

```
let scene = GameOverScene(size: self.view!.bounds.size)
self.view!.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```